# How to use update sql query in ubuntu?

Tags: database, magento-1, sql

I want to update my database **table** and I'm using ubuntu.
Following is my code,

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
$id = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id->getCustomerId());        
$salesex = $customer->getSalesExecutive();
$query = "UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET sales_executive = ".$salesex." WHERE entity_id = " . $orderId;
//print $query; exit();
$write->mysqli_query($query);
```

When I print this query, it shows fine and well. But when I run it, it shows this error **Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::mysqli_query()** 
How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$write->beginTransaction();
$query = "UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET sales_executive = '".$salesex."' WHERE entity_id = " . $orderId;
                //print $query; exit();
$write->query($query);
$write->commit();
```

also read how to use [direct queries](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/)

Comment: Not working dear! @FmeExtensions

Comment: @KazimNoorani check the error in error log `var/log` folder

Comment: @KazimNoorani update the code kindly try and feedback.

Comment: No. Still not working! @FmeExtensions

Comment: @KazimNoorani direct query is working?

Comment: @KazimNoorani this query is working for me i tested it. kindly check your column `sales_executive` exist

Comment: Ah! When I inject it through phpmyadmin sql, its working fine for me too. But not by this way. Don't know why! @FmeExtensions

Comment: @KazimNoorani i run it through code there is also working `$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$salesex='dsfdsfds';
$orderId='41'; 
$query = "UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid SET status = '".$salesex."' WHERE entity_id = " . $orderId;
                //print $query; exit();
$write->query($query);
$write->commit();` remove `var/cache` folder then try

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to execute the raw UPDATE query is :

```
$write->query($query);
```

Comment: Its not working simply using query() . Thats why I tried other way but resulting same. @ManashviBirla